# Remove public from URL Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel 5.3 is there a easy way to remove public from URL? is it necessary to add a htacces. when I change the htacces it is getting a n error like below,

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

copy both htaccess and index.php file from public folder to root directory and then change root index.php code as below

```
require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Comment: It's too risky. It makes your composer.json, .env and others sensitive information accessible via browser. Best practice is to set vhost to /public.

Comment: @MahfuzulAlam.Thanks for notifying in comment

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have to say this. It's a really bad advice since if you do that, you'll catch a lot of errors during development and whole you app code will be open to the web.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin. i hope he is using localhost otherwise he would have pointed domain to public folder itslef

Answer (score 3):

> After installing Laravel, you should configure your web server's document / web root to be the public directory. The index.php in this directory serves as the front controller for all HTTP requests entering your application.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/installation#configuration

Do not edit `.htaccess` or Laravel related files, just [point web server to a `public` directory instead of Laravel project directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507209/how-to-hide-config-files-from-direct-access):

```
DocumentRoot "/path_to_laravel_project/public"
<Directory "/path_to_laravel_project/public">
```

Then restart Apache.

Comment: This is the correct approach but Latest XAMPP (32-bit) on Windows 7 is not playing nicely. So, my team is implementing the Accepted answer given above.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `.htaccess` file in root which contains -

```
RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is very simple no need to add extra htaccess,

1. Create a new folder in your laravel project folder.
2. Name it whatever you like. Example :- source

[image]

3. Move all the files from root  into 'source' folder except 'public' folder.

[image]

4 . Move all the files from public folder to root.

[image]

5 . Change the autoload.php path

6 . Thats all.  remove public folder if necessary.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> In the root directory create a .htaccess file and put the following in
>   it

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Even above solution(s) work(s) for you,but I would recommend not to do this. 
Here is the reason why.**
-You should be pointing your Apache host root to the $LARAVEL_PATH/public directory instead of $LARAVEL_PATH.
 
-you have to configure apache for user not access .env, git files , config folder's file    
public directory is there for reason to make project a bit more secure. Solve the actual problem and don't try to break this simple but nice security addition.

Answer (score -1):

Copy all files and folder from public folder to root folder and edit your `.htaccess` file as

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And dont forget to change the paths in index.php file.
For details refere following links

[Installing Laravel in a subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12782699/installing-laravel-in-a-subfolder)

https://ellislab.com/forums/archive/viewthread/151342/#734511